# Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: css, font-face

Based on research I did about this, it'd seem that some of my headers aren't set correctly, and I have no idea how to fix this. Do I need to change a few config files on the server?

Backstory: There's a website with a few pages hosted on another server (I know, it's horrible). The site is using a custom font. It works fine on the pages housed on the server holding the fonts, but the other server isn't loading the fonts. After poking around in Firebug I learned that when the page requests the font files, the server returns a status 200OK, but the response field is blank. This happens for all font formats (eot,woff,otf,ttf).

I really need some help on this. Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't both the font and the file need to be on the same server for this to work?

I know the 'Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream' warning is because the mime type is not set in chrome yet and I generally don't worry about it. It is basically Chrome saying 'I don't know what this is'. You can set custom mime types to get rid of the warning if you want.